# ODBC connection to SQL Server 2012 LocalDB instance

Tags: c#, odbc, sql-server-2012, localdb

We have a "legacy" application, which uses ODBC connections to an underlying database, which can be Access, Oracle or SQL Server. For unit (or, perhaps more properly, "integration") test purposes, I'd like to hook up a SQL Server 2012 LocalDB instance. However, I cannot figure out a correct ODBC connection string to use.

I have tried:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void OdbcConnectionToLocalDb()
    {
        string connectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;Trusted_Connection=Yes;SERVER=(localdb)\v11.0;Description=LocalDB;";
        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new OdbcCommand("select * from Person", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                // ... 
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when the connection is opened, the following exception is thrown:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider:  Could not open a connection to SQL Server [67]. 
ERROR [HYT00] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
```

Is it possible to connect to a SQL Server 2012 LocalDB via an ODBC connection/driver? Is it possible to connect to a specific file?

**[EDIT]**
Garrett points out it is possible, great. I must have the connection string wrong, so my question really should be: what should the connection string be?

Comment: Also maybe some useful information here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/

Comment: Thanks, @AaronBertrand. That does have some useful information, but I can't see anything that specifically helps with my issue, re. getting a valid ODBC connection string to my LocalDB.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment, and not an answer. :-) Can I ask why you are connecting your legacy application to LocalDB instead of a normal Express instance? Your connection string looks like it's the kind that's used to spawn up an instance of the LocalDB engine and then do something like create a database. If you have already created an instance and created a database, I would expect to see more "stuff" in your connection string, and a more specific `SERVER`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, great questions! The "legacy" app has code which will generate a schema in a specified DB. I want to have a LocalDB .mdb file  that contains the base, empty DB, which then gets populated by this auto-schema-generating code, then run unit (or "integration") tests against this disposable DB. I guess I'm really asking: What "stuff" do I need in my ODBC connection string to connect to a specific LocalDB file?

Comment: Well I don't see a database or data file mentioned there at all. What database is Person in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify your connection string like this:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0
```

The main thing I think is that you reference it as a data source rather than server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Make sure you install the latest driver: SQL Server Native Client "Denali" (for ODBC and OLE DB).

Look here for more info:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Garrett. Glad that it **is** possible, that's what I'd hoped. I've downloaded and installed the latest SQL Server Native Client (from here, by the way: http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=29065, look for "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client"). However, I don't seem to have the connection string right, as I still get the same error as above.